# Python turtle bgpic instantly disappears

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to run a code in PyCharm and when i use code below blank window open and closes instantly.

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(600, 400)
screen.bgpic('map.png')
```

is this PyCharm issue or incomplete turtle? Fairly new to all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the help text on `turtle.bgpic()`.  When you read it, you'll see that only *.gif files are supported for turtle window background pictures:

```
>>> help(turtle.bgpic)
Help on function bgpic in module turtle:

bgpic(picname=None)
    Set background image or return name of current backgroundimage.

    Optional argument:
    picname -- a string, name of a gif-file or "nopic".

    If picname is a filename, set the corresponding image as background.
    If picname is "nopic", delete backgroundimage, if present.
    If picname is None, return the filename of the current backgroundimage.

    Example:
    >>> bgpic()
    'nopic'
    >>> bgpic("landscape.gif")
    >>> bgpic()
    'landscape.gif'

>>>
```

First convert your `map.png` file into a GIF file which should work better.  Second, generally turtle code requires a final statement like:

```
turtle.mainloop()
```

Or one of it's companions (`done()`, `exitonclick()`).  This turns over control to the tkinter event handler.  In a program like this that doesn't do anything with events, it's still needed as the program just falls off the bottom of the script and quits otherwise.  Some environments, like IDLE, don't need the `mainloop()` call, but when in doubt, include it.

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak, in the PyCharm environment, you may need a `turtle.mainloop()` as the last statement in your code.

Comment: It worked. If you could write it as an answer i could accept it. And could you please explain me why `turtle.mainloop()` is necessary in PyCharm?

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak, I've added the `mainloop()` explanation to the end of my answer per your request.  The PNG vs. GIF part is still applicable.